# Any dependency not download in maven

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, maven-plugin

I have tried with add maven plugin below listed
1)market place 
2)hlep->new install Software ->add new -> M2E and location http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/
3)I have also tried to download appache maven and follwed below URL step
http://o7planning.org/en/10101/install-maven-into-eclipse

But WhenI add new Maven Project I get error like as 
It's not allowed download any existing depedency or add into Pom.xml

1)Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:
2)Could not resolve archetype org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:1.1 from any of the configured repositories.
Could not resolve artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:1.1
Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:1.1 from

I have try to remove m2/repositories .lastmodified file 
It's not work

Any other soluation please let me know

Comment: You probably cannot access Maven Central. Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: actually i don't know about proxy could you help me for that

Comment: Maven tries to contact MavenCentral to download the artifacts. This obviously fails for some reason. The most common reason is that you are behind a company proxy that blocks certain http addresses. So it is probably a network problem.

Comment: Thank You. Any other solution for artifacts and mavencentral.

Comment: Next time you try, do not remove the `.lastUpdated` files without reading the traces within.

Comment: @LittleSanti  I was try it but it not work.

Comment: @ValaManoj You should also try outside Eclipse: Ensure you have installed Maven, open a shell and type `mvn clean`.

Comment: mvn clean give me error :[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this di
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the follo
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MissingProjectException